# How to have multiple cells in a singular row delete when cell in column A is deleted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Is there a way to delete multiple cells in a row at the same time. For example, I need A2, E2,G2,H2,I2 to all delete at the same time in a google sheet. I know you can install a button, but I need this to work for all rows, but just those specific columns. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onEdit Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to delete specific columns on a single row every time column A was deleted.

**Sample Code:**

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.range;
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();

  //Check if modified cell is in column A and in sheet1 and if cell is blank(deleted)
  if(col == 1 && sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && cell.isBlank()){
    //Delete Column E(column index 5)
    sheet.getRange(row, 5).clearContent();
    //Delete Column G to I (column index 7,8 and 9)
    sheet.getRange(row,7,1,3).clearContent();
  }
}
```

### What it does?

1. Get the sheet where the cell is being modified using `e.source` [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to get the active spreadsheet then use [getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivesheet) method to get the active sheet.
2. Get the modified cell range using `e.range` [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) then get the row and column index using [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow) and [getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn) method respectively.
3. Check if the modified cell is in column index 1 (for Column A), check if modified sheet is your desired sheet name (example "Sheet1") then check if the current modified cell is blank using [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)

> This condition is necessary to make sure that the deletion of cell will be done when column A of a specific sheet was deleted. Unless you want it to be applied in all of your sheets, then you can remove the checking of the current sheet name.

4. Select the range of cells to be deleted using [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) or [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) then delete its content using [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)

> [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) will only delete the content of the cell and will leave the formating intact. If you want to delete all cell content including the formatting, then you can use [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear) instead.

**References:**

- [Google Sheets Edit Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Class Sheet - to see all methods that can be used in a sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range - to see all methods that cab be used in a range of cell/s](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

---

**Before Cell A2 was deleted:**

[image]

**After Cell A2 was deleted:**

[image]